# How can call a (dll) C# classes: field, method or property; from VBA routine?

Tags: c#, vba

I want have relation and exchange between VBA and C#.

I have some classes in C#, and need to use methods, fields and properties from those in VBA.

Comment: check [https://www.codeproject.com/](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/555660/Extend-your-VBA-code-with-Csharp-VB-NET-or-Cpluspl)

Comment: VBA is not .NET aware. You will need to work with COM which was made for such purposes (as in: communicating between multiple programs/languages)

Comment: These are my 5 cents - http://www.vitoshacademy.com/vba-add-a-c-library-to-a-vba-project/

Answer (score 2):

In the VBE tools under references, you can add "Microsoft Visual Studio .NET VB and C# Project Model".  This should contain the namespaces you'll need for working with C#.